# How to use decorator?

Tags: python, ironpython, decorator

In SharpDevelop, I want to create a dll which contains a static methon, void Main(string[] args).

Some one said I should use decorator to restrict the function in IronPython.

I found "@staticmethod", but others, "void", "string[] args", how to restrict them?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @staticmethod   
    def Main(args):
        pass
```

Comment: To be another program loaden. UG/NX, maybe you never heard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't have return types. Just don't return anything. You can do this either by using an empty return statement or by not using a return statement at all

Comment: You can actually define return types in IronPython using clrtype.returns() decorator, to make it a clr method, which has return types.

Comment: @ jcao219 :But, What about arguments?

Comment: 不客气 （I believe you are Chinese)

Comment: @ jcao219:Yes. But my english is poor so that administrators always edit my questions for grammar like "be loaded" to "be loaden",^_^.